# How to make my Windows Server to be a Public Web and Mail Server

Tags: networking, email, windows-server-2008, web-hosting

I just installed Windows Server 2008 in my PC. I planning to use it as personal web and mail server. In the past, I used shared hosting, but since to have big storage means I need to pay more, I decided to build my own server.

In addition install WAMP for the Web server, are there anything else I need? Already own a domain name. But I thought I need to subscribe a public IP so people can connect to my PC, still I'm not sure or know how/where to get it?

And any idea about how to setup the mail server so i can get email with my domain name? Too bad that Google Apps has not free anymore, and I'm pretty sure the hotmail-domain-whatever service that currently free, will become paid service sometime. So the best bet is having own email server...

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes you need a public and static IP that doesn't change, you should contact your Internet service provider, I'm sure they can help you with that
2. In the domain manager you should point the A record @ to the specified IP
3. You should install IIS and create the website for this domain
4. For the email you can install the light version of main enable http://www.mailenable.com/ (I think it's free)

Comment: Hi, where can I find the domain manager for Windows Server 2008?

Comment: There is no domain manager, you have to install IIS (Internet Information Services). There you add a websites and in its properties you specify which domain should open this website. Also note that the same domain with and without "www" are treated as 2 websites, so in order to make them open the same you should add both . ex: google.com and www.google.com